# Описание плагина jQuery

Tags: jquery, typescript, плагин

На TypeScript делаю реализацию плагина

```js
//plugin.js
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';

(function($: JQueryStatic) {
  $.extend({
    test: function(str: string) {
      alert(str);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Создаю декларацию этого плагина

```js
// plugin.d.ts
interface JQueryStatic {
  test(str: string);
}
```

Как мне теперь эту декларацию проимпортировать в модуле?

Если пишу так

```
import * as $ from "./plugin";
$.test("AAA");
```

получаю ошибку

> Property 'test' does not exist on type 'typeof import("D:/....../ts/plugin")'

Если так

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
$.test("AAA");
```

получаю ошибку

> Property 'test' does not exist on type JQueryStatic

---

И еще вопрос: можно ли как-то использовать описания типов из plugin.d.ts в самом plugin.ts? Чтобы избежать ошибок повторного декларирования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня все заработало, когда я первой строкой в месте использования добавил

```
/// <reference path="./plugin.d.ts" />
```

Без всяких import